# Integrating Quickbooks POS with Shopify

Tags: shopify, quickbooks

I am a senior developer with C# knowledge, and i have developed many console applications and web applications which integrate with external systems using APIs. now i run my small business and i have these 2 systems:-

1- Quickbooks POS desktop application.

2- Shopify

and i want to integrate/sync these 2 platforms/systems. so when i sell something on the Quickbooks POS, to let the Shopify know about this. so i will not face an issue that i am showing an item on the Shopify which have been sold in the store(using the Quickbook POS). Now when i google this, i will get a list of paid tools which achieve this. but for me i am not sure if integrating both system is something that can be developed from scratch, by writing a console application which runs on schedule basis and update the Shopify with the Quickbooks actions?

Thanks

Comment: QuickBooks POS API: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-the-quickbooks-pos-sdk
Shopify API: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You can use QuickBooks POS API as Keith suggested to fetch orders ( or listen to webhooks if QuickBooks is providing on order create event ).

On Shopify end, you can create [Private App](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps) on your store. and create the order using the [Shopify Admin API for Orders](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order).

But while creating order on Shopify you need to pass VariantID ( if you want to track inventory on Shopify and want to keep track which exact product is sold ).

you may need to map which product ( or variant )  is sold on POS with Shopify.

Managing a local database may help you here out and you can make this mapping based on SKU.

Hope this will help.